# How to delete a string in a file with ANSI C?

Tags: c, string, file-io

I'm trying to delete a string in a data-file.

The format of the data is just like following records:

```
4253 1

3119 1

5709 1

576 1

857 1

5859 1

5896 1

116 1

2396 1

1088 1

4180 1
```

Those are a part of a file.I have no right to send img.
Each record makes up of two numbers segregated by space and segregates by invisible char '\n'.
There're thousands of records in the file, I just want to delete some records useless when i scan the file. Should use C language to implement it.

very sorry for not providing detailed format of the data.

Comment: You can do it easily in unix.. why are you going for C?

Comment: @Venk So what if the program is meant to be portable ?

Comment: Please give some more details. How are the records separated? Newline character? How are useless records identified? Specific data or some specific format? And do you really need it in C? This can be a Perl one-liner.

Comment: I'm writing some kind of program to analyse a set of data and need to delete some records in file.

Comment: What type of 'record' is undesirable? How is the file structured? Show us a sample of the data you have, and show us what you want to get rid of.

Comment: What's the criteria to determine if a record is not wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Files in C are sequential entities. Unless you impose your *own* structure on them (such as treating NUL characters as non-existent ones), the only real way to delete characters or lines is to overwrite them, shifting the part of the file following them a little towards the front.

You can either do this in-place with things like `fseek` and `truncate` (that last is not ISO C) or by reading from one file and writing to another.

For example, the following program will delete a line containing `11` from the standard input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char buff[1024];
    while (fgets (buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL)
        if (strcmp (buff, "11\n") != 0)
            printf ("%s", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Beware the usual caveats lines lines that are too long for the input buffer.

Comment: The OP didn't even mention UNIX, why does everyone start to talk about UNIX!? It might as well be a mp3 file inside a mp3 player and the program could be the firmware, for all we know. Good luck installing UNIX on that.

Comment: Good point, @Lundin, that was a brain-f*art on my part. Fixed to say "Files in C", since that is what I meant.